# Clone SpannableStringBuilder

Tags: java, android, clone, spannablestring

I am working on an Activity in which I parse a text with markup characters.
What I'm doing is converting them to several types of ClickableSpans.

The problem is that I need to implement a function (lets call it function B) that implies having overlapping ClickableSpans and that causes several issues.

So what I'm doing now is creating a new SSB while detecting the overlapping spans, and removing the ones I don't need for this particular function. Working fine.

BUT, I need to be able to go back to the previous SSB and that doesn't seem to work.

STEP BY STEP:

```
// I CREATE THE SSBs
...
static SpannableStringBuilder ssb;
static SpannableStringBuilder ssbCopy;

// I IMPLEMENT MY CUSTOM FUNCTION THAT PARSES THE TEXT AND SETS THE SBB AS A TEXTVIEW CONTENT
...
textView.setMovementMethod(new LinkTouchMovementMethod());
ssb = addClickablePart(chapterTextStr, markupCharactersArray);
textView.setText(ssb);

// WHEN A BUTTON IS CLICKED I IMPLEMENT MY FUNCTION B. WHERE I CREATE A COPY OF MY ORIGINAL SSB AND STORE IT IN ssbCopy, AND SET IT AS THE TEXTVIEW CONTENT
...
ssbCopy = SpannableStringBuilder.valueOf(ssb);

// I REMOVE THE OVERLAPPING SPANS
...
overlapSpans = ssbCopy.getSpans(index, index+word.length(), TouchableSpan.class);

for (int c=0;c<overlapSpans.length;c++) {                       
    ssbCopy.removeSpan(overlapSpans[c]);
}                       

// I SET THE NEW CLICKABLE SPANS
...
ssbCopy.setSpan(touchableSpan, index, index + word.length(), 0);

// AND SET THE NEW SSB CONTENT TO THE TEXTVIEW
textView.setText(ssbCopy);

// EVERYTHING WORKS FINE UP TO HERE
// BUT WHEN I TRY TO SET BACK THE ORIGINAL SSB BACK AS THE CONTENT OF MY TEXTVIEW WHEN THE USER CLICKS A BUTTON
...
textView.setText(ssb);

// THE ORIGINAL SSB IS EXACTLY LIKE THE COPY (ssbCopy) AND CONTAINS THE SAME CLICKABLE SPANS I ADDED. NOT ONLY THE ORIGINAL ONES
```

I guess it may sound somewhat confusing and I'm not sure if I explained properly, but I can't get around this.

**EDIT:**

As per kcoppock answer, I learn it isn't possible to clone an ssb and valueOf(ssb) is just a copy of the object.
So I ended up cloning my "ssb" manually by looping through all elements and applying them to the new ssb. Like this:

```
TouchableSpan[] spans = ssb.getSpans(0, ssb.length(), TouchableSpan.class);

ssbCopy = new SpannableStringBuilder(chapterTextStr+"dsadsa");

for (int c=0;c<spans.length;c++) {
    TouchableSpan obj = spans[c];

    ssbCopy.setSpan(obj, ssb.getSpanStart(obj), ssb.getSpanEnd(obj), 0);
}
```

By the way, TouchableSpan is a custom class I created that extends ClickableSpan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is your use of `valueOf()`. It doesn't do what you think it does. All it does is return the object passed in, if it is a `SpannableStringBuilder`; otherwise, it wraps the given `CharSequence` in a `SpannableStringBuilder`. From the source:

```
public static SpannableStringBuilder valueOf(CharSequence source) {
    if (source instanceof SpannableStringBuilder) {
        return (SpannableStringBuilder) source;
    } else {
        return new SpannableStringBuilder(source);
    }
}
```

So essentially:

```
ssb == SpannableStringBuilder.valueOf(ssb);
```

They are one and the same Object. `SpannableStringBuilder` does not implement `Cloneable`, so there's no easy way to make a copy, other than to just generate two copies, for example:

```
ssb = addClickablePart(chapterTextStr, markupCharactersArray);
ssbCopy = addClickablePart(chapterTextStr, markupCharactersArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for your clarification about valueOf() ! At least I know where the problem resides now. However, I can't implement the generate two copies solution, because I need my copy to have the changes done to the ssb after it was stripped from the markup characters. Will keep trying. Any further ideas appreciated!

Comment: Well, I ended up cloning the ssb "manually". Your answer was the one that let me knew what was wrong, so, marked as correct.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the only way to go, honestly. Just throw that in a utility class somewhere and save it for later. :) I think you can just pass in `Object.class` to get all span types (if you end up needing more than just `TouchableSpan` cloned).

Answer (score 3):

The method subsequence in [`SpannableStringBuilder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html#subSequence) copies the spans. You could make a copy of you ssb by calling `ssb.subsequence(0, ssb.length)`

```
SpannableStringBuilder ssbCopy = (SpannableStringBuilder)ssb.subSequence(0, ssb.length());
```